# Hide the ImageView after the Frame by Frame Animation stops in android

Tags: android, animation, imageview, hide

I just applied Frame by Frame animation in the image view , i just use 2 images in frame by frame

main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView1);

    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);
    AnimationDrawable ac= (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
    ac.start();

    //ac.stop();
if(ac.isRunning()==false){
        iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
        }
```

animation.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="1000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="1000"/>
 </animation-list>
```

activity_main.xml(layout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Im also confused where to stop this Animation 
and i need to hide the image view after the 2 image animated and restart the animation later on

i'm Working on Advertisement images. so i need to show the images for short duration and later it will restart again.

If anybody know this solution . please help me.

Answer (score 0):

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView1);

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);
AnimationDrawable ac= (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
ac.start();
```

You can simply put an empty picture as last item in the animation:

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot="true"
 >
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="1000"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="1000"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/dummy" android:duration="1000"/>

     </animation-list>
```

and oneshot=true.

To restart , you could call an onClick method and call start again like this:
 Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView1);

               iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);
               AnimationDrawable ac= (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
              ac.start();

        }
```

Comment: Nice idea, how to restart some animation again?

Comment: @AnanThDev if it is correct then flag my answer:). Anyway, I added some code reto start animation.

Comment: @Gynonder: I Dont use Button.. Because I'm implementing Advertising using imageView as different frames.Any other Idea?

Comment: @AnanThDev , so it is a loop. If you put android:oneshot="false" and increase the <item android:drawable="@drawable/dummy" android:duration="60000"/> these ads would rotate . Or maybe I don't understand well what you are going to do.